# How to create an Edit method in this situation? ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, controller, asp.net-core-mvc, action

I tried to create an Edit action based on another controller.

But in this particular case, I can't do it.

I don't use a separate model for my post replies, but keep it based on the post ID.

This is what I tried

[Get] **Edit** method from controller:

```cs
[Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
            if (userId == null)
            {
                return View("AccessDenied");
            }

            var rep = _context.PostReplies.Find(id);

            if (rep == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"Post with ID = {rep} cannot be found";
                return View("NotFound");
            }

            PostReply reply = _context.PostReplies.Find(rep);

            if (reply == null)
            {
                return View("NotFound");
            }

            if (userId == reply.User.Id || User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("Mod"))
            {
                return View(reply);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("NotFound");
            }
        }
```

[Post] Edit method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Edit([Bind(include: "Id, Content, Created, Updated")] PostReply reply)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Entry(reply).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Manage");
            }
            return View(reply);
        }
```

This is "model" **PostReply**:

```cs
using System;

namespace collector_forum.Data.Models
{
    public class PostReply
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Which is declarated in my **ApplicationDbContext**

```cs
public DbSet<PostReply> PostReplies { get; set; }
```

This is my part of HTML code resposible for displaying post replies.

```html
@if (Model.Replies.Any())
    {
        foreach (var reply in Model.Replies)
        {
            <div class="row replyContent">
                <div class="col-md-3 replyAuthorContainer">
                    <a class="userName" asp-controller="Profile" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-id="@reply.AuthorId">
                        @reply.AuthorName
                    </a>
                    @if (reply.IsAuthorAdmin && Model.IsAuthorMod)
                    {
                        <div class="isAdmin smaller">Admin</div>
                    }
                    else if (reply.IsAuthorMod)
                    {
                        <div class="isMod smaller">Mod</div>
                    }
                    <br />
                    <span class="postDate">@reply.Date</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9 replyContentContainer">
                    <div class="postContent">
                        @Html.Raw(reply.ReplyContent)
                    </div>
                </div>
                @if (Model.AuthorName.Contains(User.Identity.Name) || User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    <span class="col-auto">
                        <a asp-controller="Reply" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@reply.Id" class="btn btn-editPost">
                            Edit Reply
                        </a>
                    </span>
                }
                else if (Model.AuthorName.Contains(User.Identity.Name))
                {
                    <form asp-action="Delete" asp-controller="Reply" asp-route-id="@reply.Id" method="post">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"
                                onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete post: @Model.Title')">
                            Delete
                        </button>
                    </form>
                }
            </div>
        }
    }
```

With the current code after clicking "Edit" [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pELxA.png) shows up

And here my question arises, is it possible to implement this action in a different way?

**//EDIT**

Problem is that the function "Find" doesn't find other values except "Id", "Content", "Created", "Updated". To let logged user to edit his own reply I need to get user details and post details ex. userId, UserName, postId.. etc.

This are values of properties - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDXuj.png)

Comment: can you add here the ReplyController class - line 114 (entire method that contains that line, please)

Comment: Method contains line 114 is [HttpGet] Edit Method @madoxdev

Answer (score 0):

You can change your Edit Action like this:

```
[Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
            if (userId == null)
            {
                return View("AccessDenied");
            }

            var rep = _context.PostReplies.Find(id);

            if (rep == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"Post with ID = {rep} cannot be found";
                return View("NotFound");
            }

            if (userId == rep.User.Id || User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("Mod"))
            {
                return View(rep);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("NotFound");
            }
        }
```

You have got rep with `_context.PostReplies.Find(id);`,So you don't need to use `PostReply reply = _context.PostReplies.Find(rep);`, and check if it is null again,also you need to put an int type rather than `PostReply` into `_context.PostReplies.Find(xxx)`.

Comment: Yes it's null again, but here `if (userId == reply.User.Id || ...)`
https://imgur.com/XMaYB3U

Comment: You can check my answer,I use `if (userId == rep.User.Id ||...)` rather than `if (userId == reply.User.Id || ...)`.

Comment: `return View(reply);` I cant return value of variable "reply" - The name does not exist in the current context.

Comment: My mistake.I have updated my answer.Change  `return View(reply);` to `return View(rep);` .

Answer (score 0):

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int? id)
    {
        ViewBag.Positions = new SelectList(_context.Positions, nameof(Position.Id), nameof(Position.Name));
        var employee =await _context.Employees.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
        if (employee == null) { return NotFound(); }
        UpdateEmployeeVM employeeVM = new UpdateEmployeeVM
        {
            Name = employee.Name,
            Surname = employee.Surname,
            PositionId = employee.PositionId,
            FacebookUrl = employee.FacebookUrl,
            TwitterUrl = employee.TwitterUrl,
            InstagramUrl = employee.InstagramUrl,
            Salary = employee.Salary,
            ImgUrl=employee.ImageUrl
        };
        return View(employeeVM);
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).